# Parsing String to int on TextChangedListener

Tags: android

I have 2 editText, each one convert between lbs to kg.
when user type number in one editText and then try to edit the second, i get NumberFormatException: Invalid int.
[image]

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        switch (et.getId()) {
            case R.id.kg: {
                v2.removeTextChangedListener(watcher2);
                if (s.length() < 1) {
                    v2.setText("");
                } else {
                    v2.setText(toKG(s.toString()));
                }
                v2.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.lbs: {
                v1.removeTextChangedListener(watcher1);
                if (s.length() < 1) {
                    v1.setText("");
                } else {
                    v1.setText(toLBS(s.toString()));
                }
                v1.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private String toKG(String input){ 
        return "" + Integer.parseInt(input) * wKG; 
    }
```

Comment: Please put the code of `toKG()` and `toLBS()`

Comment: @fiddler    `private String toKG(String input){
        return "" + Integer.parseInt(input) * wKG;
    }`  the toLBS do the same thing but division instead of multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Integer.parseInt()` expects a string containing an integer, and it will fail if the string contains a floating number.

Try this:

```
private String toKG(String input) {
    return Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(input) * wKG);
}
```